# JavaFX BorderPane.setCenter(SubScene) does not display subscene content when generated from FXML file

Tags: java

Having constructed a GUI from SceneBuilder based upon a BorderPane layout I cannot display the items in subScene assigned to the Center region. When building the application without an FXML file the contents are displayed.

```
   Group objects = setGroup(width, height);
   Group group = new Group(objects, camera, spot, light);
   SubScene subScene = new SubScene(group, 600, 550, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
   BorderPane borderpane =  new BorderPane(null, menubar, null, sliders, null);
   borderpane.setCenter(subScene);
   Scene scene = new Scene(borderpane, 600, 600);
   stage.setScene(scene);
```

The above works fine when borderpane is instantiated within start(Stage stage) but if borderpane is referenced from the FXMLController

```
   Group objects = setGroup(width, height);
   Group group = new Group(objects, camera, spot, light);
   SubScene subScene = new SubScene(group, 600, 550, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
   BorderPane borderpane = controller.getBorderPane();
   borderpane.setCenter(subScene);
   Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
   stage.setScene(scene);
```

Comment: The provided pieces of code are not enough to test and reproduce your problem, consider posting the FXML file as well.
see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. The problem did not lie with the injection of the subScene into the borderpane but with setGroup(width, depth) where the parameters were both zero. The objects could not rendered since they were out of scene.